# Getting Next page URL from database?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am getting next page URL from database in Oracle Apex but every time page logout.
my URL for next page that is save in database is :
f?p=312.:112:&APP_SESSION.::::P312_ID:704

Answer (score 2):

```
f?p=312.:112:&APP_SESSION.::::P312_ID:704
       ^
       |
  what is this dot doing here?
```

Comment: i removed that dot, but still nothing happened.

Comment: I don't know how you created URL, but I'd suggest you to use APEX_PAGE.GET_URL function (https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/GET_URL-Function.htm#AEAPI30190)